# Why is there an upper bound for structure size in the universe?

Tags: astrophysics

The [Hercules-Corona Borealis Great Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules%E2%80%93Corona_Borealis_Great_Wall) is often said to be the largest structure in the universe, and to cross a certain upper bound for the size of structures. For instance in [this article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/05/27/biggest-thing-in-universe-video_n_5365111.html), a writer quotes an astrophysics professor saying:

> The Her-CrB GW is larger than the theoretical upper limit on how big
>   universal structures can be [...] Thus, it is a conundrum: it
>   shouldn’t exist but apparently does.

My questions on this subject are:

- how is the word "structure" being defined in this context? In which sense can the whole observable universe not be considered as a single structure?
- given the definition used, why is there an upper bound for such structures?

Comment: These bounds are model dependent. If reality tells us that our model is wrong, then we dump our model into the waste basket and build a better model. I would suggest not to take pop-science articles on these issues too seriously and read the papers of the modeling folks, instead. As for the definition of structure, I would suggest that it would be better to go to a spatial frequency representation and look at the spectral shape (slope) rather than the spatial structures directly.

Comment: My question was not why a certain structure is larger than what is/was currently understood as the upper bound, but _why_ is there an upper bond at all. I also have the impression that the negative vote I got (and probably will get more) is for quoting a pop science article. While I am quite aware of the problems with this sort of publication, I am simply not able to read field specific articles given  my layman nature. But if for some reason the question is not considered to belong in this website, then once this is explained to me I'd gladly remove it.

Comment: That said, given that questions such as http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25179/why-do-astronomers-say-that-there-is-not-enough-matter-in-universe?rq=1 seem to be acceptable, I wonder what's the problem with mine.

Comment: Your question implies that there is an upper bound for a property of the universe and logically such questions don't make sense within a scientific framework. We have one universe, not an ensemble of universes. We could only establish upper bounds on an ensemble of measured structures. For the one measurement that we have it's at most a question of why some model predicts the wrong large scale structure.

Comment: Well, the astrophysicist quoted is the one implying it, not me. So unless the author of the article used extremely unethical quote mining techniques or unless the astrophysicist over simplified something, then I still wonder what is the problem with my question. But your last two phrases does make sense to me and sheds some light on the issue, so thanks a lot for that.

Comment: That's why I said that one should not rely on pop-science articles. Even for a scientist it's easy to say something utterly nonsensical in an interview. Statements of this nature are usually vetted by multiple rounds of peer-review with students, colleagues etc. and the actual peer reviewers before papers get printed. It's a hard process to make only scientifically correct statements. In front of a journalist even scientists will make poorly reasoned statements that sound similar, but are completely wrong. And even if they are not, the editorial process may distort them by taking out nuances.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Come on, your sophistic comments about models are technically right, but "What is the astrophysical model that predicts this upper bound and how is the upper bound arrived at?" is still a perfectly valid question about astrophysics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: The problem isn't that we can't construct models that predict upper bounds. The problem is simply that we don't know what the upper bound is. I am the last person to believe in the multiverse, but that is exactly what one would need for a statistical analysis of something like an upper bound. I did, by the way, give a hint of how I would approach this, by looking at the low frequency slope of spatial frequency distributions. I did look at the "source", btw and it's like I feared: the guy sent them an email and they picked one sentence rather than print what he said in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have dark energy (which gives you a distance-dependend repulsion), plus gravity (which gives you a distance-dependend attraction), you can calculate the distance where the gravitational attraction between two bodies cancels with and gets overwhelmed by the dark-energy repulsion (see [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248991)). On large scales this works the same way, with the difference that you don't use the mass, but the density distribution. So the very large (seemingly) gravitationally bound structures you are asking about could imply that there is either more density than expected from the average fluctuations, so dark energy could cancel the gravitational attraction not until a larger spatial separation than normally, or less dark energy (which is rather unlikely since the cosmological constant should be constant).